# Mercurial on Mac and Windows - without admin?

Tags: macos, mercurial, portability

My workflow includes having to develop at work (a University) where I don't have admin/install rights on a Macintosh OSX workstation. Right now I just use a USB stick to carry the code around, but this is so very old fashioned and makes no good use of source control principles.

I want to start using Mercurial (and/or Kiln) for my work, but is there anyway I can do so in this environment? I'm willing to use GUIs, command line, workarounds like using any weird free portable IDE configuration solely for use of a portable Mercurial plugin, etc.

I can find plenty of links for doing this on Windows, but not Mac. At the very minimum I need to be able to commit and update my local code. Everything else would be icing on the cake, but I'd settle for really minimal functionality on Mac. If need be I can do more intensive operations on own windows laptop where I can install anything I want, but without commit in a locked-down Mac environment it'll be nearly useless in my work.

Added Detail: My work is mainly web development, most recently jQuery/HTML5. My workflow mainly uses Dreamweaver for code editing and design, which is pleasantly available on all Mac workstations at my University.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use of Mercurial does not require admin rights. It does seem that the official Mercurial installer requires admin rights (because it wants to put things in `/usr/local/bin`), though, which is a shame.

If you look round for graphical Mercurial clients, you will find that some of those do not require admin rights to install or use. [MacHg](http://jasonfharris.com/machg/) doesn't seem to, for example. Download, unzip, run, enjoy. [Murky](https://bitbucket.org/snej/murky/wiki/Home) also has a zip download, so i'd guess that was the same. [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) has a .dmg which opens to reveal a copyable application, so that also shouldn't need admin rights - it suggests you copy it to the Applications folder, but you can put it anywhere.

I would imagine that all of these programs include a copy of the actual Mercurial somewhere. In MacHg's case, it's at `MacHg.app/Contents/Resources/localhg`. You can use that from the command-line as usual.

Comment: That's wonderful to hear! I'm not terribly familiar with Mac user rights, and rather assumed "install" of any of these on OSX was analogous to a Windows install (not being able to update Flash or Firefox without admin rights made me assume perhaps too much). I'll try out MacHg and/or the others first chance I get (after the holiday break). Thanks so much!

Comment: One of the small but comfortable things that has always been the case on the Mac is that an application is just a bunch of files. You can copy them wherever you like and run them. You don't often actually want to do that (you'd rather install them in the Applications folder properly, or let an install package take care of things), but sometimes, it comes in handy!

Comment: Finally got my rep up enough to accept answer and upvote - thanks for the help Tom Anderson!